# Apple.com style Localization

Tags: localization

Its it possible to use the localization feature to create regional site versions.

Currently when I attempt to use this feature I can only view pages in my locale.

The Apple.com website shows a great example of what we're trying to achieve.

```
http://www.apple.com/au/
http://www.apple.com/nz/
http://www.apple.com/uk/
```

We'd like to create new entries and have a draft appear in all regional sub directories.

E.g.

```
http://www.acme.com/nz/news/news-release
http://www.acme.com/au/news/news-release
http://www.acme.com/uk/news/news-release
```

...

The main point is we want the entire site open to users from anywhere.

We're not yet concerned with translations either.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the event system to catch requests to certain areas of the site and force the locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some helpful advice via Craft's support channels. Here was the solution I arrived at with their assistance:

You can hard code the locale in index.php in the doc root.

```
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', $locale);
```

The normal approach seems to be that multiple index.php pages can be used in a multi-locale site. I prefered to keep the one, so I used this tiny hack that derives from the url what the desired locale is:

```
<?php

// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

$url_folder = substr(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), 0,
    strpos(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), "/"));
$locale = 'en_nz';

if($url_folder === 'worldwide') {
    $locale = 'en_zz';
}
else {
    $locale = 'en_' . $url_folder;
}

define('CRAFT_LOCALE', $locale);
```

This hack is confined to the index.php so it seems pretty clean.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel & Tonic added an article on this some time ago which explains everything very well: https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide

**And it just rulez!**